# Did Craig steal the boxes?

Tags: friday

The classic film "Friday" opens with main character Craig (Ice Cube) explaining that he was fired from his job a shipping company.

"They said they got me on video, stealing boxes," Craig says.

When someone asks if he really did it, he says "I didn't steal any damn boxes," but at least to me, this denial doesn't sound very convincing. And Craig doesn't mention anything about trying to defend himself.

So I've always wondered.. did Craig steal the boxes?

Comment: I think we can only speculate... Either way it was meant as a reason for him being unemployed that friday.

Answer (score 2):

If he did, he probably would have told Smokey, his best friend. Plus, he woulda had some money or something from it, and they wouldn't have almost got killed by Big Worm.